# How to chose EC2 cluster type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-rds

I want to implement a very simple server side application for a mobile game mainly to serve my needs for analytics and tweak some settings on the fly.

- The game is a single player game
- At the launch of every session, the game downloads about 5KB worth of settings
- After each game/loop the game sends server about 10KB of data and store it for analytics.
- Then I crunch this data and tweak some settings so that they get downloaded in the subsequent sessions. Kind of Live Ops
- I am leaning towards a AWS solution, but I dont have much idea on what to chose. Some basic questions

EC2 clusters : 
There are EC2 clusters. Assuming if I have 10,000 players with 3 sessions a day - can I go with t2 Large or m4.10x large or somethign else ? how do I chose ?
Also I want to know, if suddenly number of players go to 1 million, do I need to buy more instances or buy 1 powerful isntance ?

RDS: 
For my usecase, do I need a RDS instance to store the data ? as I understand, EC2 is only computing power to run my server side app and not store any data in databases. For storing about 10MB of data everyday, a db m1 large should suffice ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, it seems like you can go for a serverless solution like AWS Cognito Sync to synchronize users session data and have a Lambda function to execute for analytics where you can decide to store this information in a Database.

This solution will give you the lowest total cost of ownership while you pay only for the AWS resource usage while having scalability, availability, and fault-tolerance by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real answer for what sized instances and database you need. The only way to determine this is to test your application by simulating workloads and seeing how your application performs. Tweak the instance size, database size, etc for each different test and compare what works best.

At a higher-level, however, you could consider a **serverless solution** using **API Gateway and AWS Lambda**. This will automatically scale to whatever workload you require and you only pay for compute time actually used.

As for a database, **Amazon DynamoDB** is a fully-managed NoSQL database that can scale based upon workload. It's a cloud service, so there is no database server to manage.

Such serverless approaches require a different approach than traditional programming -- it is responsive and *event-based* rather than having an application looping forever, waiting for traffic. It's highly likely that it will work out cheaper too.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I chose ?

U fortunately we don't know what your system requirements are.  One of the best things on AWS is you can test on the production scale. So you can really do some load testing and see how your system behaves

As well you can start with some baseline setup and change your instance sizes as needed.

Other answers suggest going serverless and with the numbers you've provided it may be good idea if you can write your app that way. Note that the serverless option may be more expensive under serious workload, however I believe you could benefit from it greatly.

> Also I want to know, if suddenly number of players go to 1 million, do I need to buy more instances or buy 1 powerful isntance ?

If you could write your app that it could scale horizontally (that adding more servers would increase the system performance), you could set the system to scale up and down automatically and you could start with smaller instances ( servers would be started and stopped as needed by itself )

> RDS: For my usecase, do I need a RDS instance to store the data

If you need a relational database, rds is great option. It has built in high availability and disaster recovery.  However RDS doesn't scale automatically, so if you expect going to really high peak traffic, you may consider using some caching or DynamoDB. That scales itself.

> . For storing about 10MB of data everyday, a db m1 large should suffice ?

The instance size affects available maximum iops, memory and cpu, so it depends on your workload what is needed. For small data throughput and simple selects you can really start with something smaller (t2.small?) and see how it behaves.